# How to disable auto suggestion of Edit text in Android version 10 i.e. Android Q?

Tags: android, android-edittext, autosuggest, android-10.0

[image]

I have tried all the options which are available i.e. **textNoSuggestions**, **textFilter**, **textMultiline**. But they didn't work for me. So, after using all these I even tried to set inputType from java file but even that didn't work either.

I have my EditText in ConstraintLayout.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share the xml code?

Comment: <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/Eg_email"
            android:inputType="textFilter|textNoSuggestions"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
            android:singleLine="true" />

Comment: @hfarhanahmed i have put given my edit text xml in commet section thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you have textFilter in your inputType?

Comment: @hfarhanahmed ok,so now just for your sake i have remove textFilter from inputType and no i am just using textNoSuggestion ,then to i am getting suggestion,i m trying to post a image so that u can see my issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below inputType and it will work -

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thats strange how a password input type could give suggestions?

Comment: yes ik but the fact is that i am getting suggestion,i have shared a image you can look into it

Comment: As per your screenshot in question I can't see any suggestion text with keyboard.

Comment: rm808022@gmail.com is the suggestion which i am getting on the first edit text please check once again

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is not *autosuggestion* but *[autofill](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill)*. Make sure you've not set `android:autofillHints` and remove it if it is set.

You can also try to set `android:importantForAutofill="no"`